# How do I keep a list between button clicks?

Tags: c#, list, button, click

So as a learning process i'm trying to do some few exercises i put myself up to, so i'm trying to get a button to give me a random value between the list i have, but when he clicks the button again i want another random value excluding the one it just used. It should be working fine except that the list appears to be "rewritten" after each click, i assume this is happening because the code is the button click event, so i have 2 questions: How do i make this work as it is (meaning i keep the list where it is, i just make it so it doesn't get "reseted"), and Where could i put the list instead, so that it doesn't get "reseted" after each button click, but with me being able to use it on the button click event. I have tried putting it everywhere else and it just says "the name vowelz does not exist in the current context".

```
 public void vowelbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random randomizer = new Random();

        List<Keys> vowelz = new List<Keys>();
        vowelz.Add(Keys.A);
        vowelz.Add(Keys.A);
        vowelz.Add(Keys.A);
        vowelz.Add(Keys.B);

        var indexz1 = randomizer.Next(0, vowelz.Count);
        var keyz1 = vowelz[indexz1];
        listBox1.Items.Add(vowelz[indexz1]);
        vowelz.RemoveAt(indexz1);

    }
```

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or Web Forms, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to declaring `List` in another method? It wasn't accesible by `vowelbutton_Click` method. This should work.

```
List<Keys> vowelz = new List<Keys>
{
    Keys.A, Keys.B, Keys.B, Keys.B
}

public void vowelbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random randomizer = new Random();

    var indexz1 = randomizer.Next(0, vowelz.Count);
    var keyz1 = vowelz[indexz1];
    listBox1.Items.Add(vowelz[indexz1]);
    vowelz.RemoveAt(indexz1);
}
```

Comment: this is what i wanted, thank you so much, i didn't know i had to declare it as a method like that to make it work in other methods :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this...

```
public class MyClass 
{
    protected List<Keys> vowelz = new List<Keys>();

    public void vowelbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random randomizer = new Random();

        vowelz.Add(Keys.A);
        vowelz.Add(Keys.A);
        vowelz.Add(Keys.A);
        vowelz.Add(Keys.B);

        var indexz1 = randomizer.Next(0, vowelz.Count);
        var keyz1 = vowelz[indexz1];
        listBox1.Items.Add(vowelz[indexz1]);
        vowelz.RemoveAt(indexz1);

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with this example by repeated hitting the button...

```
    private List<Keys> tmpVowelz = null;
    private Random randomizer = new Random();
    private List<Keys> vowelz = new List<Keys>() {
        Keys.A,
        Keys.A,
        Keys.B,
        Keys.B
    };

    public void vowelbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tmpVowelz == null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            tmpVowelz = new List<Keys>(vowelz);
        }
        if (tmpVowelz.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = randomizer.Next(tmpVowelz.Count);
            Keys key = tmpVowelz[index];
            listBox1.Items.Add(tmpVowelz[index]);
            tmpVowelz.RemoveAt(index);

            if (tmpVowelz.Count == 0)
            {
                tmpVowelz = null;
            }
        }
    }
```